# Not response from server in JSON request

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am working on a login system for an iOS app.

I am now testing the response from remote server.

This is the function for the LOGIN button in the app:

```
   @IBAction func btnEntrar(_ sender: Any) {




        let correo = txtEmail.text!
        let pass = txtPassword.text!

        if(correo == "" || pass == ""){
            print("campos vacios")

            return
        }


        let postString = "email=\(correo)&password=\(pass)"

        print("envar solicitud \(postString)")


        let url = URL(string: "http://.../login.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"//tipo de envio -> metodo post
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)// concatenar mis variables con codificacion utf8

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {//si existe un error se termina la funcion
                self.errorLabel.text = "error del servidor";

                print("solicitud fallida \(String(describing: error))")//manejamos el error
                return //rompemos el bloque de codigo
            }

            do {//creamos nuestro objeto json

                print("recibimos respuesta")



                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] {


                    DispatchQueue.main.async {//proceso principal

                        let mensaje = json["mensaje"]//constante
                        let mensaje_error = json["error_msg"]//constante
                        let error_int = Int(json["error_msg"]!)//constante
                        print("respuesta: \(mensaje_error ?? "sin mensaje")")

                    }
                }

            } catch let parseError {//manejamos el error
                print("error al parsear: \(parseError)")
                self.errorLabel.text = "error del servidor (json)";

                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("respuesta : \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

And this the PHP file that is receiving the request.

```
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);


if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);

    if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        $response["user"]["imagen"] = $user["imagen"];
        $response["user"]["nombre"] = $user["nombre"];
        $response["user"]["apellidos"] = $user["apellidos"];
        $response["user"]["nivel_usuario"] = $user["nivel_usuario"];
         $response["user"]["unidad"] = $user["unidad"];
        $response["user"]["id_usuario"] = $user["id_usuario"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong credentials! Please, try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;

    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I am not getting any error or exception, but the last output I receive is

```
print("recibimos respuesta")
```

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT

Demo JSON output

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameters email or password is missing!"}
```

Comment: Because the response data is not a JSON format or the JSON format is not [String:String]. If you not hesitate provide the url or Update question with demo JSON output.

Comment: @RAJAMOHAN-S, I have updated my question with a demo JSON output for blank parameters

Comment: Try my solution will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response `Object` contains not only `String`. It contains `Bool` also. You could use like below,

```
 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] { //Any for, Any data type
    //Do with json
    print(json)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add content type header to the request like this (Objective-C):

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: According to question the body data is not JSON.

Comment: But it looks like server wants some dictionary with email and pass, not a string like this "email=\(correo)&password=\(pass)"

Comment: See the PHP code bro `if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {}`

Comment: the answer from RAJAMOHAN-S works.Thank you for your effort.